# Based in the US; can I purchase PS Plus for a UK-based player?

Tags: region-lock, playstation-plus

As the title says: I'm a PlayStation User in the US, and I'd like to purchase PlayStation Plus time for a friend of mine who lives in the UK. The [PlayStation Store](https://www.playstation.com/en-ae/get-help/help-library/playstation-plus/playstation-plus/gifting-or-transferring-playstation-plus/) suggests the correct way to do this is to buy a top-up code or PS Plus gift card from them and give the code to my friend:

> You can buy a wallet top-up voucher code and the recipient can add these funds to their wallet to buy a PlayStation Plus membership from PlayStation Store. You can also buy a PlayStation Plus membership gift card or voucher code in a variety of high street and online retailers and the recipient can redeem this on their account.

But I can't find information anywhere about whether those codes are country-specific, and, if they are, whether the PSN store would allow a US user to purchase a code from their [UK site](https://store.playstation.com/en-gb/product/IP9102-NPIA90006_01-PSPLUS1MONTH0001).

Anyone have any insight here?